# Custom edit button in data grid view

Tags: sql-server, datagrid

```
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection

    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClinicConn").ConnectionString

    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Patients_tab SET Waiting=@Waiting WHERE ID=@ID"

    conn.Open()

    Dim btn As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    btn.Parameters.Add("ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    btn.Parameters("@ID").Value = ID
    btn.Parameters.AddWithValue("Waiting", "0")

    btn.ExecuteScalar()

    conn.Close()

    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView2.DataBind()
```

Try to add this code in a custom button to change a value of "Waiting" col from "1" to "0" and remove the row from DG1 to DG2, I got this error

> A SqlParameter with ParameterName '@ID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Comment: It's **custom** - not "costume" .....

Comment: Any help Please